# jQuery grid numbering system with each or for

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to give elements a numbering system that would correspond somewhat like a grid (think excel sheet).

I have elements in a container somewhat like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ele"></div>
    <div class="ele"></div>
    <div class="ele"></div>
    <div class="ele"></div>
    <div class="ele"></div>
    <div class="ele"></div>
    <div class="ele"></div>
    <div class="ele"></div>
    <div class="ele"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to use jQuery to iterate through each element with a variable number of "columns"

I can't seem to figure out when to use a for loop or just to use .each().

```
$('.ele').each(function(){
    var col = 3;
    for(var i = 0; i < col; i++){
        $(this).addClass('row' + i);
    }
});
```

I know this would only give me each row number and even then I don't think this is correct, but then how do I get column numbers in there as well?  I would like the output to be this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ele row0 col0"></div>
    <div class="ele row0 col1"></div>
    <div class="ele row0 col2"></div>
    <div class="ele row1 col0"></div>
    <div class="ele row1 col1"></div>
    <div class="ele row1 col2"></div>
    <div class="ele row2 col0"></div>
    <div class="ele row2 col1"></div>
    <div class="ele row2 col2"></div>
</div>
```

so, I know this code is completely wrong, but I actually don't even know where to start.  For loop first? then element?  I'd like to try not to use `:nth-of-type()` if at all possible, but if it has to be, then I can make it work.

Once I get this figured out, I can ask the bonus question... it throws a wrench in the entire thing, but I need to understand this first.

Thank you!

Comment: I have a question for you. Your data is obviously a table - you are trying to replicate table features - why are you not using a table? The `don't use tables` "mantra" for web development doesn't apply to cases where a table **is** the preferred choice.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not a table.  I am pulling a lot of information on each "ele" and I am placing them in a number of columns dependant on screen size.  It will eventually be responsive so a table will not do.

Comment: In this case...would you prefer a JS-less solution?

Comment: not necessarily.  I will be adding this to an already extensive jQuery script and will also be modifying it.  I think in a few years when speed matters, I will go towards JS.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.container div.ele').each(function(i) {
    var columnsPerRow = 3;

    var row = Math.floor(i / columnsPerRow);
    var col = i % columnsPerRow;

    $(this).addClass('col' + col + ' row' + row);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hGNLb/3/

Comment: Wow, I always forget that the each function can bring in the index.  Thank you!